# How to append a row to a table with td{element) data previously fetched from JSON and parsed into an object

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

I fetched JSON and parsed it into an object which I passed to a function that will add a row for each object and it's specific data

```js
fetch('gamesApi.json')
  .then((response)=>{
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((result)=>{
    displayGamesObject(result,displayGames);
  })
  .catch(()=>{
    console.log(new Error('Error Occurred.'));
  });
```

then I have these two functions

```js
function displayGamesObject(gameObjects,callback) {
  gameObjects.forEach(game => {           
    callback(game)
  });
}

function displayGames(game) {

  document.getElementById('game-list-table').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',`
<tr>
  <td>${game.id}</td>
  <td> <a href=${game.url} target="_blank"><img src=${game.photo} alt="Photo"></a> </td>
  <td>${game.name}</td>
  <td>${game.publisher}</td>
  <td>${game.rating}</td>
 </tr>
  `);
}
```

After that everything is added but in total mess I would like for it to be added in row in table i selected.
After everything is done i get this and i dont want it to be displayed like this i want it to be in rows like in normal table.
[image]

Comment: *"...but in total mess."* is a virtually meaningless statement. Please explain problem with a reasonable level of technical detail.

Comment: @charlietfl I fetched JSON data (Game list with names,rating,photo,publisher) and after page load i want to display that i a table so after fetching JSON and parsing it into an object i want those separate objects to be displayed in rows of a table i selected previously.

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong with the code shown? You haven't detailed a specific problem with it

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry for saying that i meant all data is displayed but not in the way that I wanted but contrary games are not displaying in rows but are just being added without order.

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about order in the question. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue as well as ordering requirements

Answer (score 0):

If your table has an ID, you can target it with `document.getElementById` and then use the built in append method to append the `<tr>` if you are using it as a javascript object. You could also (however I do not suggest this as it can be used in XSS attack) use the `innerHTML` attribute and just append the HTML onto the table body at the end using a template string or just the + operator.

As mentioned in the comments, you can also use Table.insertRow() and Row.insertCell() to accomplish this. (credit: @charlietfl)

Comment: Using `Table.insertRow()` and `Row.insertCell()` would be far more practical than innerHTML

Comment: I agree, as well as it  being far safer. I will add that to my answer.